# Property Settings are not loading in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My Google analytics are not loading any of Property Settings for any website. I can't add tracking code to my website as I can't see it. None of the other functions under Property Setting in Admin of Google analytics for any website are loading.

I tried to un block any blockers in Google Chrome for no relsuts. I posted 3 times my request on google analytics help forum - no reply. I have been having this problem for months now. 
The same problem applies to firefox browser. Nothing is loading.

Please help! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have right permissions? If you are a user with View level permissions, you may not see the property settings

Comment: Thank you, Sandeep for your suggestion. It looks like I have all permissions set up : Edit, Collaborate, Read and analyse, but still, everything is just a white field. I have been trying to find any contact details of google analytics to contact them directly but it looks like their contact details don't exist, only through forums like this one...

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am having the same trouble ...